# Does this matrix exist?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\mathbf{ABD=0}$, $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are known and $\mathbf{A}$ is $M \times N$, $\mathbf{B}$ is $N \times R$, $\mathbf{B^HB=I}$ and $\mathbf{D}$ is $R \times R$. Does $\mathbf{D}$ exist such that $\mathbf{D^HD=I}$ where $\mathbf{H}$ is the conjugate transpose. $\mathbf{BD}$ is generally known, it can be computed as the null matrix for $\mathbf{A}$, but I'm more interested in the solution the gives $\mathbf{D^HD=I, D\neq I}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If such a $D$ exists in $M_R(\mathbb{C})$, then $D$ is invertible by $D^*D=I_R$. So $ABD=0$ implies $AB=0$.

Now if $AB=0$, then any $D$ such that $D^*D=I_R$ works. That is the set of unitary matrices in $M_R(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I should've mentined $D \neq I$. I updated the question

Comment: @SoCal93 Id does not change much. Your solution set is the set of unitary matrices $D$.

Comment: Thank you, so it exists only if $AB=0$. In my case $AB \neq 0$, so I can't find a matrix with $D^*D=1$

Comment: @SoCal93 Yes, that's what I've observed: such a $D$ exists if and only if $AB=0$, in which case the solution set is the set of all unitary matrices.

Comment: I dont think it's entirely true that if $D^HD=1$, then $D$ is invertible. there are rectangular (non-invertible) matrices that satisfy $D^HD=I$

Comment: @SoCal93 But you said $D$ is $R\times R$...This is true for square matrices. Otherwise, of course, a non square matrix is never invertible...

Comment: my bad, I just noticed that I put $D$ as a square matrix, I updated the question.

Comment: for the sake of the answer provided above, I'll update the question and leave $D$ as square matrix, as the answer is given for a square $D$.

Comment: @SoCal93 Ok. Then if you want, you can ask another question.